# How to assign numeric values to multile strings in a dataframe column using python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to train my model with a data frame containing company_name (Categorical feature) and some values in int (that i want to predict).

Since there are multiple different values in the column 'company_name' how can I convert them to numeric type?
(It is easier to convert them to int/float when there are very few of them, like in the iris flower datasets we can easily assign numeric values since there are only 3 species)

I want to know the best way to assign numeric values to a categorical featured column having lot of distinct values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Category Codes [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# creating initial dataframe
bridge_types = ('Arch','Beam','Truss','Cantilever','Tied Arch','Suspension','Cable')

bridge_df = pd.DataFrame(bridge_types, columns=['Bridge_Types'])

# converting type of columns to 'category'
bridge_df['Bridge_Types'] = bridge_df['Bridge_Types'].astype('category')

# Assigning numerical values and storing in another column
bridge_df['Bridge_Types_Cat'] = bridge_df['Bridge_Types'].cat.codes

>>> bridge_df
  Bridge_Types  Bridge_Types_Cat
0         Arch                 0
1         Beam                 1
2        Truss                 6
3   Cantilever                 3
4    Tied Arch                 5
5   Suspension                 4
6        Cable                 2
```